# JSON API Document de-serializing and serializing using Spine Swift Library

Tags: json, swift, serialization, json-api

I'm using Spine [A Swift library for working with JSON:API](https://github.com/wvteijlingen/Spine)

*I want to understand how to serialize the data to take full advantage of the JSON API's*

I'm using **Serializer** to achieve this as:

```
   let serializer = Serializer()
   serializer.registerResource(MyModel.self)
```

What i have got ?

```
  let document = try! serializer.deserializeData(data) //data is my response as NSData
```

I'm able to get the JSON API Document with all the included relationships and data as

```
  document.included
```

For this I'm casting MyModel to the required data as

```
  MyModel   = document.included[0] as! MyModel
```

**As this is not the intended way to fully utilize the JSON :API, any suggestions and what am i missing ?**